# CSS vertically space even divs in IE 11

Tags: css

I was creating a layout which worked in the latest updated browsers (Firefox, Chrome, ...) and then opened the layout in IE 11 and saw a difference. My layout in IE looks like this:

[image]

But in every other tested browser the space on the right sided divs is evenly between them, which means that the third div stays on the bottom, while the second divs is right in the middle. I can't get it working in IE 11 and hoped that someone from here has a good advice.

https://jsfiddle.net/1gq2cj3f/2/

```
<article class="col-12 content-wrapper">
<div class="row content-wrapper-materials">


<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 materials-sectors">
    <div class="card materials-sectors-general">

        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-12">

                <header class="card-header">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <a href="...">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="" width="568px" height="430px">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                        <h3 class="card-title">    
                            Allgemein                        </h3>
                    </div>
                </header>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 materials-sectors">
    <div class="materials-sectors-specific">

                    <div class="card specific-construction">
                <div class="row no-gutters">

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                        <header class="card-header">
                            
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <a href="...">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="" width="190px" height="117px">
                                </a>

                                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">
                                        Headline                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                        <div class="card-body" itemprop="description">              
                            <p class="card-text">
                                Text                           </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="card specific-healthcare">
                <div class="row no-gutters">

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                        <header class="card-header">
                            
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <a href="...">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="" width="190px" height="117px">
                                </a>

                                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">
                                        Headline                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                        <div class="card-body" itemprop="description">              
                            <p class="card-text">
                                Text                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="card specific-ict">
                <div class="row no-gutters">

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                        <header class="card-header">
                            
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <a href="...">
                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="" width="190px" height="117px">
                                </a>

                                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">
                                        Headline                                   </h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </header>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                        <div class="card-body" itemprop="description">               
                            <p class="card-text">
                                Text                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</article>

.content-wrapper > div {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 8rem;
    padding-bottom: 8rem;
}

.card > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.materials-sectors .card-header {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(242, 241, 241, 1) !important;
}

.materials-sectors .card-image {
    height: 100%;
}

.materials-sectors .card-img-top {
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.materials-sectors-general .card-img-overlay {
    bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 0.75rem;
}
.materials-sectors .card-img-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    top: auto;
}
.card-img-overlay > h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.materials-sectors-specific {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.materials-sectors-specific > .card {
    height: 100%;
}

.materials-sectors-specific .card-image {
    display: block;
}

.materials-sectors-specific > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Have you asked yourself if you even *need* to support IE? Because it will probably make things a lot more complicated. More and more applications and websites just don't support IE anymore (which is a good thing in my opinion).

Comment: That's a good question. I came around the term "cross browser testing" and read everywhere that it is important for your website and it gives me headaches when trying to apply my CSS to IE or older versions. I think it would be good to have it working in IE 11 but if you think it is not so important then I can live with it.

Comment: I don't think it is important in most cases. It depends on what you are trying to do and what your target users are. If your target users consist of older people it is more likely that they use a deprecated browser, therefore, making it necessary to support IE.

Comment: The majority of new projects don't support IE anymore. Even Microsoft itself stopped support. If it's not in your contract that you have to support IE, just forget about it. It's old, it's ugly, and everyone hates it.

Comment: And don't get me wrong, cross browser support is important, but you also don't need to support Chrome versions that are 10 years old right?

Comment: Absolutely depends on what your intended audience is. I support a tiny charity's website and many of the users are members who are stuck with hand-me-down PCs so still use IE, but if you are not in that situation then you could forget it , or put up with a slightly non-ideal look on the website, as recommended by others here.

Comment: Thank you both guys for clarifying this. It really helped me.